# What explains the errors in geography in "Transformers: Revenge of the Fallen"?

Tags: transformers, transformers-live-action-series, transformers-revenge-of-the-fallen

**There are a number of weird errors in geography in *Transformers: Revenge of the Fallen*.**

Just from the Egypt sequence;

- At the start of the film, we see the Pyramid of Giza surrounded by huge mountains, a lot of huge mountains. Those [shouldn't be there](https://www.google.com/maps/@29.9777084,31.132859,3a,69.9y,105.48h,100.62t/data=!3m8!1e1!3m6!1sAF1QipOAl31lxNRbLEe3IccpESjBbfBuem0WblBXEsTg!2e10!3e11!6shttps:%2F%2Flh5.googleusercontent.com%2Fp%2FAF1QipOAl31lxNRbLEe3IccpESjBbfBuem0WblBXEsTg%3Dw203-h100-k-no-pi-18.37739-ya125.78889-ro-0-fo100!7i8704!8i4352).
- Cairo in the movie is too far away. In reality some houses are built almost against the pyramids.
- Sam travels from Cairo to Luxor (Karnak) in a matter of minutes. In reality it's 600+ km
- The quarry where the Decepticons forms Devastator doesn't exist.
- We see at least one tank brought on shore by a boat and joining the battle. The closest distance the Nile is from the pyramids is 8 kilometers.

**Is there an in-universe or out-of-universe explanation why the geography in *Transformers: Revenge of the Fallen* doesn't match up with real-world geography?**

Comment: Like are you asking if there is supposed to be an alternate history that explains the differences? Or alternately, a statement about the mistakes?

Comment: I've done an edit to make it less ranty about continuity errors and focus on the geography issue you've raised.

Comment: For the record, this is answerable.

Comment: I don't think this is answerable in a meaningful way. Movies make geographical errors all the time, either unintentionally or intentionally (see "artistic license"). e.g. https://www.elitereaders.net/geography-mistakes-in-movies/, https://www.reddit.com/r/movies/comments/86wllr/which_films_get_geography_horribly_wrong/

Comment: @NathanGriffiths - It's answerable in the sense that the maker has spoken specifically to the issue of the dodgy geography in his film

Comment: In Octopussy (1983) James Bond's plane lands with the Taj Mahal in the foreground, and thus at Agra.  Bond gets in a taxi which takes him to Udaipur 631.9  kilometers away, a 10 hour 40 minute drive, in just a few minutes.  Movies are full of crazy geography.

Answer (score 3):

Bay addresses this in the audio commentary for *Revenge of the Fallen*. Real-world geography simply has to take a back seat when it comes to telling an evocative and exciting story with multiple recognisable locations, referring to those who get hung up about that sort of thing as "*geography buffs*".

> **Bay:** ***Most people have never been to this brand new Smithsonian museum which exists in Washington, which is at Dulles airport. Now, I
>   wanted to shoot in this airforce base in Tucson,*** which is a
>   gigantic... it's not a wrecking yard, but it's a yard where they
>   reclaim every single plane that's ever been flown in the air force and
>   they use them for parts. There's actually a section of this
>   gigantic... and I'm talking it's miles of desert, and they line up
>   these planes in a very organised fashion, and actually the Russians to
>   this day keep it still on satellite every day because they want to
>   know if we're moving or parting out any of our B-52 bombers which are
>   still, we have a bunch of bombers there and if we need spare part for
>   our B-52 bombers, which are the ones that carry the nuclear weapons.
>   It sounds very cold-war era, but this is where every single plane in
>   the air force, unless it's crashed, goes to this yard.
>
> ***For the geography buffs, I didn't pull it off, but for most people, in Taiwan, don't know where this museum and this Arizona airfield
>   exist and so this my way of jumping time, well, not jumping time but
>   jumping locations by showing the desert outside this museum***

Note that if the filming locations (Giza and Luxor, for example) were '*real-world*' accurate, the locations depicted in the film would be hundreds of miles apart and would take entire days of travel to get to.